# Why am I getting wrong result with multiplication (*) in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and just want to calculate the number of mili seconds in a year, but the result is not as expected

```
long milisecondsInYear = 1000*60*60*24*365;
System.out.println(milisecondsInYear); // Expect 31536000000 but get 1471228928
```

Please advise me on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: this has cross the range of long.

Comment: You're doing all the math in `int` arithmetic.

Comment: use `1000L*60*60*24*365` (note L)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do any calculations java just assumes and calculates it as an int, even if you're saving the result in a long variable.

The actual result can't fit in the `int`variable, hence you get that value.

To solve the problem you need to add an `L` at the end to let java know this is actually a long.

```
long milisecondsInYear = 1000*60*60*24*365L;
System.out.println(milisecondsInYear); // Expect 31536000000 but get 1471228928
```